# Maven uber-jar generation uses application.properties of dependency instead of its own

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, properties-file, uberjar

I have a quarkus maven project which has properties in `src/main/application.properties`. This project also has a local dependency that also contains `src/main/application.properties` since there are tests in the dependency that rely on it (setting them in `src/test/application.properties` does not work). Example folder structure:

- `dependency`

  - `src/main/application.properties` (contains some settings for integration tests in this dependency)
- `quarkus-project`

  - `src/main/application.properties` (contains different settings for its own project)

When i build an uber-jar for the `quarkus-project` it successfully creates one, however it contains the `application.properties` file of the dependency instead of its own.

Uber-jar contents generated for quarkus-project:

- ...
- `application.properties` (<- file from `dependency`, rather than from `quarkus-project`)
- ...

Why is that? Why does it use the `application.properties` of a dependency rather than its own when building the specific project? Is there a way to specify a priority or such?

Comment: There isn't really a way to control this. This particular case is arguably a bug, but in general you can easily run into such problems with uber-jar

Comment: @geoand i see, is there a way to add some form of custom step in the build process? or do i rather need to use gradle if i want to do something like that? like for example change the application.properties when copied to the uber-jar or anything like that.

Comment: I don't remember for sure, but I don't think there is any integration point for the uber-jar generation process.